# How much did the Apollo boilerplate rockets cost?

Tags: apollo-program, cost

The point of a boilerplate is to test out the features of a system at a reduced cost. I would like to know what it cost to build the Apollo boilerplates. There was a series of such rockets so I would appreciate any cost data available on any of them.

Comment: The Apollo boilerplates were not only used to test the rocket, they were used to test the launch escape system and different critical phases of reentry and landing of the capsule.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding NASA boiler plates for the Apollo program, [one source](http://www.jonessite.net/upload/LRD/stories/1227withpics.pdf) claims,

> The 1200 series were manufactured by a firm called Ace Fabrications
>    in Clute, Texas, each costing some $10 – 15K.

Comment: Interesting article, and good source. +1