# Cost of making a capsule boilerplate

Tags: capsule

I am a space enthusiast, and i wanted to know a rough estimation of the cost of making a *capsule boiler plate*. I searched in google, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: any rough estimation?

Comment: I didn't know that capsules have boilers, and even less so that capsule boilers had plates! It might be a good idea to explain exactly what a *capsule boiler plate* is for readers like me. Thanks!

Comment: There are so many different versions and types of dummy capsules with so many different sets of features, the price can be anywhere between the pure prices of raw materials and the price of a fully equipped space vehicle.

Comment: It's not a source I trust, but [this](http://www.astronautix.com/n/nasaslostbotoryofbp-1227.html) suggests some of the Apollo boilerplates were $10-15K (in 60s dollars)

Comment: @uhoh not a capsule but shuttle had boilers: https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/technology/images/sts-wsb_9-small.gif

Comment: Does wood count?  (some of the Buran boilerplates)

Comment: @DrSheldon anything that is needed in making boilerplates count.

Comment: other boilerplate sightings: [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43719/12102) and also [How much did the Apollo boilerplate rockets cost?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22188/12102)